# Mysql Count related records not counting

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a multiple tables for a library database and I want to count a how many publications has been lent to a certain group.

I have these tables

**Patrons table**

```
CREATE TABLE `patrons` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Patron Categories**

```
CREATE TABLE `patron_categories` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `overdue` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Publications**

```
CREATE TABLE `publication` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(24) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Checkout**

```
CREATE TABLE `checkouts` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `publication_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `patron_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `checkout` date NOT NULL,
  `checkin` date NOT NULL,
  `actual_checkin` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my query to list patron categories with their total patrons and their current number of publications their checkout out.

```
SELECT pc.NAME                 AS Category, 
       Count(p.id)             AS patrons, 
       Count(c.id)         AS publications 
FROM   patron_categories AS pc 
       JOIN patrons AS p 
         ON pc.id = p.category_id 
       LEFT JOIN checkouts AS c 
              ON c.actual_checkin = NULL 
       LEFT JOIN publication AS pub
              ON c.publication_id = pub.id 
GROUP  BY Category
ORDER BY Category
```

I don't know what's wrong but it gives the number of publications as 0 while there are many publications lent to those patrons.
Any help please.
The full database with dummy data is located [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sggh6xh6lart2p6/library.sql?dl=0).

Comment: Try removing the `group by` and `count` columns, and execute what's left with `select *` - do you see what you expect? Once you get that query right, just add the counts and group by back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT pc.NAME                 AS Category, 
       COUNT(p.id)             AS patrons, 
       COUNT(c.id)         AS publications 

FROM   patron_categories AS pc 
       JOIN patrons AS p 
         ON pc.id = p.category_id 
       LEFT JOIN checkouts AS c 
              ON c.patron_id =  p.id
       LEFT JOIN publication AS pub
              ON c.publication_id = pub.id 
GROUP  BY Category
ORDER BY Category
```

**The Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good except for checking if the `c.actual_checkin` field is null. Try changing the join statement to from `ON c.actual_checkin = NULL` to `ON c.actual_checkin IS NULL`